# OWASP ZAP: Enabling script

Tags: scripting, zap, fuzzing

Please is there a way to auto enable a script on owasp zap?
my script keeps disabling in few seconds after enabling it. what could be the problem?

Comment: thank you Simon Bennets... your response was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

ZAP will disable scripts if they fail to compile.
Open the script and look in the Script Console - that will show you any compilation errors.